# How to get iOS device token in Kony studio app

Tags: ios, temenos-quantum

I am an iOS developer & currently working on an app in Kony studio. I have to send iOS device token on server for Push notification via a json service. Is there any way/api in kony studio to get iOS device token?

Any help or idea would be great for me.

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.kony.com/tutorials/MobileFabric/Content/Overview.htm#UsingMesiOS ?

Comment: @Larme thanks, bit I don't have to use Kony mobile fabric iOS sdk. I have to get device token using Kony studio.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am using in my Kony Studio project:

```
        subscriptionArguments.deviceId = kony.os.deviceInfo().identifierForVendor;
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using Kony visualizer 7.x. And use the code as below to register the device for push notification.

```
        try {
          setStatus("Getting device info.."); //Own function
          messagingClient = client.getMessagingService();
          var osType = "";
          if(kony.os.deviceInfo().name=="iphone" || kony.os.deviceInfo().name=="iPhone"){
                osType = "iphone";
            }else{
                osType = "androidgcm";
          }
          var deviceInfo = kony.os.deviceInfo(); 
          var deviceId = deviceInfo.deviceid;
          var userId = emailId;
          messagingClient.register(osType,deviceId,deviceRegID,userId,pushSubscriptionSuccessCallback,pushSubscriptionErrorCallback);
          setStatus("Subscribing..");
        }catch (e) {
            kony.print("Error while subscribing the device " + e);
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

var deviceInfo = kony.os.deviceInfo();

var deviceID=deviceInfo.deviceid;

Above Code will give device ID for anddroid, but for IOS it will give 02:00:00:00:00:00, which is not helpful.

You can do it using below code for IOS.

var deviceID= deviceInfo.identifierForVendor;----for and above 6.0 and

var deviceID= deviceInfo.customdeviceid;----- below 6.0

Reference: http://docs.kony.com/5_6_PDFs/Kony_API_Reference_Guide.pdf